# In ORACLE SQL is it possible to get sum of all different category values in a end row where that individual category ends?

Tags: sql, plsql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in which there are different categories. I want to display sum of Total amount for every category values in a row where that individual category ends.IS it possible write a SQL select query for this.

**OUTPUT:**

| category | Amount | Totalamount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 |  |
| A | 10 |  |
| A | 5 | 35 |
| B | 15 |  |
| B | 5 |  |
| B | 14 | 34 |
| C | 25 |  |
| C | 5 | 30 |

Comment: What do you mean by `where it ends`? Data is not stored in a sorted manner. How do you know that A-5 is the last row for Group A? Is there a timestamp column that you're not showing, something that would represent `ends`?

Comment: Yes,timestamp is there but date doesn't matter. We have to sort it only with category column for what ever the date it has.

Comment: What if two rows have the same amount? If you don't use the timestamp, then what would differentiate Category A Amount 5 from Category A amount 5 (ie, two rows with the same category and amount). On which row do you add the total sum? I recommend using a timestamp if that's unique for row by category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using window function `row_number()` to order data, `sum() over()` to get sum by category, then a left join to the subquery where we have got the sum and the latest record per category :

```
with cte1 as (
  select category, amount, row_number() over(order by 1) as rn
  from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select category, amount, sum(amount) over(partition by category) as sum, row_number() over(partition by category order by rn desc) as rn
  from cte1
),
cte3 as (
  select category, amount, sum
  from cte2
  where rn = 1
)
select t.category, t.amount, c.sum as Totalamount
from cte1 t
left join cte3 c on c.category = t.category and c.amount = t.amount
order by rn
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/aCI-NB6z)

Answer (score 0):

You need something such as date or timestamp to differentiate one row from the next in case you have a Category with more than one row of the same amount. Here's a solution that uses a CTE to help determine which row should get the total.

```
create table table1 (
  category varchar(5), 
  amount integer, 
  order_date date
  );
```

```
insert all
 into table1 (category, amount, order_date)  values ('A', 20, DATE '2022-01-01')
 into table1 (category, amount, order_date)  values ('A', 10, DATE '2022-01-02')
 into table1 (category, amount, order_date)  values ('A', 5, DATE '2022-01-03')
 into table1 (category, amount, order_date)  values ('B', 15, DATE '2022-02-01')
 into table1 (category, amount, order_date)  values ('B', 5, DATE '2022-02-02')
 into table1 (category, amount, order_date)  values ('B', 14, DATE '2022-02-03')
 into table1 (category, amount, order_date)  values ('C', 25, DATE '2022-03-01')
 into table1 (category, amount, order_date)  values ('C', 5, DATE '2022-03-02')
select 1 from dual;
```

```
with cte1 as (select category, max(order_date) as max_date, sum(amount) as total_amount
  from table1
  group by category
  )
select t.category, t.amount,
  case when t.order_date = c.max_date then c.total_amount end total_amount
from table1 t
join cte1 c
  on t.category = c.category
order by 1
```

| CATEGORY | AMOUNT | TOTAL_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | *null* |
| A | 10 | *null* |
| A | 5 | 35 |
| B | 15 | *null* |
| B | 5 | *null* |
| B | 14 | 34 |
| C | 25 | *null* |
| C | 5 | 30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7-4h0sbz)

If you don't want to use date, then randomly sort using something like `row_number() over (partition by category order by dbms_random.random)` to get a row number and then add the total to the row with the max rn per category. However, that seems like a mess considering you have a date to work with. Or just use a spreadsheet since the output is not typical.